# How do I authenticate a 'super user' to access information on a user's behalf?

Tags: php, ajax, security, rest, authentication

I created a REST web service that uses an access token to allow authenticated/authorized users to access 'private' data. I'd like my website to use the same API to access data on the user's behalf via AJAX but am unclear to do so securely. Here's an example: while the user is not allowed to delete their own account, I (the website), can. That said, if authenticated as the website, I should be able to delete the user by sending a DELETE request to the appropriate URL. The trouble is, sending an all-powerful 'god token' along with the request doesn't work because the token would be visible to the end-user. That said, what's the standard for accomplishing this? Separate APIs? Cookies? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to be able to delete the user account 'as the website', does that mean you want to do it client-side, from javascript? If you are the one doing the DELETE, which end-user are you worried about seeing the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a "superuser" or "user_level" column to your user database and add that to the session when you login.

Then you can check before you execute a delete:

```
if ( 
     ($_SESSION['current_user_id'] === $id_to_be_deleted)
     || ($_SESSION['superuser'] === 1)
   )
                                    ^ for example...  
{
  // delete
```

(loads of new-lines and parenthesis in an attempt to make it clear...)